# How I can connect to mongo db in my java application?

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to connect a java application with mongo db so how i can connect mongo db. what kind of driver i must use? is it possible to connect?

I followed this youtube tutorial but I can't understand it clearly.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rnA6wpF0o4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this references to solve your problem. It will help you. [mongo DB java driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/)

and you can connect mongo DB to java applications.